# Parse a word document using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, doc

I need to parse a word document and find out some key words from that file. I have gone through some solutions to read doc files like using COM or using third party tools. Is there any other way to read word document without using these two? I am using asp.net with c#.

Comment: What version(s) of Word do you need to support?

Comment: I need to support MS Office 2007 and it's earlier versons.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IFilter interface, which is part of Microsoft's Indexing Service. It supports binary Word files. More information:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IFilter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Haven't personally used this but http://docx.codeplex.com/ is one of the recommended Word Doc Manipulation Libraries on the popular [Most useful free .NET libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662956/most-useful-free-net-libraries) post