# How to parse a word document in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word

How can we parse a word document using asp.net and c#?

The question I have is with respect to parsing a word document, say a resume, to read the contents like name and email address. For this, I have an idea, but not sure of how to implement it. Can someone help me on this?
My idea is:

- Take the first line, if there are two or more words (other than curriculum vitae)separated by a single space or using a period(.) followed by a space, it is a name.
- Take the second line, if there are two or more words separated by a single space or using a period(.) followed by a space, it is a name.
- Consider the last line, if there are two or more words separated by a single space or using a period(.) followed by a space, it is a name.
- Consider the second last line, if there are two or more words separated by a single space or using a period(.) followed by a space, it is a name.

I know how to read telephone number and email using patters, but I don't know how to implement finding out the name. Is there any idea?

Comment: Check out this post to help you get started

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241973/parse-a-word-document-using-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Spire.Doc](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7a2b37c6-322b-496b-85ac-ce2768f942e5). I used this on some of my projects.